# MySql return date range in a particular week

Tags: mysql

I am able to retrieve the sum/total sales for all items in a particular week using the code below.

```
select week(real_pur_date) as week, itemcode, sum(quantity)
from sales
where week(real_pur_date) = week(20120620)
group by itemcode;
```

The output is:

```
+------+----------+---------------+
| week | itemcode | sum(quantity) |
+------+----------+---------------+
|   25 | KB001    |            11 |
|   25 | KB002    |             2 |
|   25 | KB003    |             3 |
+------+----------+---------------+
```

which is what I wanted

The question is how can I query MySql to return the range of dates in week 25 back into the result table?
For example,
1. range of dates in week 24 is 10-06-2012 to 16-06-2012.
2. range of dates in week 25 is 17-06-2012 to 23-06-2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting the *actual* boundary dates of the week, or just the dates of the first and last sales within this week? In other words, if no sales happened on 17-06-2012, then do you expect "18-06-2012" and "23-06-2012"?

Comment: @YaK I am expecting the actual boundary dates of the week

Comment: manage this in your application, not in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a MySQL guy so I had to try to convert from SQL Server functions.  But, the basic math is there.  I'll let you determine how you want to pass or calculate @YEARSTART and @YEAREND.

```
DECLARE @YEARSTART datetime, @YEAREND datatime
SET @YEARSTART='1/1/2012'
SET @YEAREND = '12/31/2012'

SELECT A.week, CASE WHEN (@YEARSTART + INTERVAL (8-DAYOFWEEK(@STARTYEAR)+(week-2)*7) DAY) < @YEARSTART 
                 THEN @YEARSTART
                 ELSE (@YEARSTART + INTERVAL (8-DAYOFWEEK(@STARTYEAR)+(week-2)*7) DAY) 
               END AS WeekStart,
               CASE WHEN (@YEARSTART + INTERVAL (7-DAYOFWEEK(@STARTYEAR)+(week-1)*7) DAY) > @YEAREND
                 THEN @YEAREND
                 ELSE (@YEARSTART + INTERVAL (7-DAYOFWEEK(@STARTYEAR)+(week-1)*7) DAY)
               END AS WeekEnd,
      A.itemcode, A.SumQty 
FROM
(
select week(real_pur_date) as week, itemcode, sum(quantity) AS SumQty
from sales
where week(real_pur_date) = week(20120620)
group by itemcode
) AS A
```

Comment: @tombom, I agree with you on managing it in your application, but I wanted to provide an SQL solution in case Boon Gǎgǎ didn't have that option.  Also, the challenge was there.  Sorry to hear you have such strong opinions on the subject.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answer and opinions. I will give it a try on both solutions.

Comment: @tombom, I completely understand.  I've had one too many of those days recently as well.  Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @HolgerBrandt Let's clean up a bit.